# PowerMockito private void method issue

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock

I have below class

```
class PowerMockitoTest{

  private void TestPrivateMethod(){
    System.out.println("Inside private method");
  }

  public void TestPublicMethod(){
    System.out.println("Inside public method");
    TestPrivateMethod();
  }
}
```

I have created Test class as below

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PowerMockitoExampleTest {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

 PowerMockitoTest testclass = PowerMockito.spy(new PowerMockitoTest());
 PowerMockito.doNothing().when(testclass,"TestPrivateMethod");
 testclass.TestPublicMethod();

}
```

}

Instead of getting OP as 'Inside public method' I am getting  very strange OP as 'Inside private method'. Though i have stubbed private method to do nothing its getting called as well as sysout for public method is not getting printed.

Its working fine when i used `PowerMockito.doAnswer()` but it requires method to be at package level instead of private.

Comment: Did you notice that you have the same names for test class and class that you wanted to exercise?

Comment: Corrected it , typed wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it this way:

```
    PowerMockitoTest testclass = PowerMockito.spy(new PowerMockitoTest());
    try {
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(testclass,  PowerMockito.method(PowerMockitoTest.class, "TestPrivateMethod")).withNoArguments();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    testclass.TestPublicMethod();
```

btw:
Testing is about mocking input and investigating outputs (it can be state of module, result of function or calls to another functions).

You should not mock private methods, as their result should not be treated as an input becouse they are not visible from outside.

Comment: Have you tried this code? It will not print "Inside public method".

Comment: I forgot about: '.withNoArguments();'

Checked it now

Comment: Inside public method

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

The missing part in your code i believe is the  @PrepareForTest part. You have to add class name with @PrepareForTest after @RunWith annotation

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Class1.class, Class2.class})
public class ClassTest
```